# SEH with RtlAddFunctionTable in manually loaded DLL

Tags: windows, exception, visual-c++, dll

I'm manually mapping a dll into a process which is compiled with (/EHa). This can catch exceptions like the one below. The problem is, since im manually mapping the dll the exceptions/functions are not registered which leads to a crash of the program as soon as a excpetion occurs. To solve this issue i came to the conclusion that i need to use this function "RtlAddFunctionTable(...)". Sadly im unable to get the first two parameters (FunctionTable and EntryCount) to call the function. Can someone help me out and tell me how i can get the first two parameters?

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    RUNTIME_FUNCTION runtimeFunction = ?;
    DWORD size = ?;

    RtlAddFunctionTable(&runtimeFunction, size, (DWORD64)hModule);

    try
    {
        int var = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(0xFFFF);
    }
    catch (...) 
    {
        cout << "Exception" << endl;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Edit, i solved it:

```
bool EnableExceptions(DWORD64 moduleBase)
{
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pDOSHeader;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pNTHeader;
    PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER pOptHeader;

    pDOSHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)moduleBase;
    if (pDOSHeader->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
        return false;

    pNTHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((PBYTE)pDOSHeader + pDOSHeader->e_lfanew);
    if (pNTHeader->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
        return false;

    pOptHeader = (PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER)& pNTHeader->OptionalHeader;
    if (pOptHeader->Magic != IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR_MAGIC)
        return false;

    PRUNTIME_FUNCTION pFunctionTable = (PRUNTIME_FUNCTION)((DWORD64)pOptHeader->DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXCEPTION].VirtualAddress + moduleBase);
    cout << "functionTable " << hex << functionTable << endl;

    DWORD sizeFunctionTable = (pOptHeader->DataDirectory[3].Size / (DWORD)sizeof(RUNTIME_FUNCTION));
    cout << "functionTableSize " << dec << functionTableSize << endl;

    BOOL success = RtlAddFunctionTable(pFunctionTable, sizeFunctionTable, moduleBase);
    cout << "RtlAddFunctionTable " << success << endl;

    return success;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are building the .DLL with SEH enabled the information you need should already be in the PE file.

According to [this blog post](https://pmeerw.net/blog/programming/RtlAddFunctionTable.html), static tables in the PE takes precedence over dynamically added tables.

If you need to use a custom table for some reason then you need to use `VirtualAlloc` to allocate memory for the table **and** the code because the addresses are relative (RVA).

Comment: Yes, the info should be in the ".pdata" section. So i need to call RtlAddFunctionTable(pDataAdress, pDataArraySize, moduleBaseAddress) since the ".pdata" section is an array of RUNTIME_FUNCTION's - but it seems like its not working as intended since the code still crashes and there is no exception fired.